# Elixir Phoenix not loading env variable at runtime

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I am trying to load an API key as a system env from my mac when starting up the phoenix server. What am I getting wrong? these are my steps:

1. On my mac terminal:

   ```
   export API_NOTIFICATION_KEY=1234
   ```
2. in my config.exs

   ```
   config :app, App.Notifications,
   notification_api_key: {:system, "API_NOTIFICATION_KEY"}
   ```
3. in my module where I use it

   ```
   @api_notification_key Application.get_env(:app, App.Notifications)[:notification_api_key]
   ```
4. start my phoenix server

   ```
   mix phx.server
   ```

And then When I try to make the API call it is showing as nil. Is there a step I am missing to get it properly loaded ?

Answer (score 4):

Attributes are evaluated during compilation, so:

```
@api_notification_key Application.get_env(:app, App.Notifications)[:notification_api_key]
```

will have its value set at compile time. I assume that's not what you want, so you'll be better off using a function:

```
defp api_notification_key() do
  case Application.get_env(:test, App.Notifications)[:notification_api_key] do
    {:system, var_name} -> System.get_env(var_name)
    value -> value
  end
end
```

Comment: *Attributes are evaluated during compilation* -- Wouldn't that only cause a problem if the op ran the app on a system different from the system on which the app was compiled?  In other words, the op claimed that the env variable was set before compile time, then the app was compiled.  Therefore the env variable baked into the app at compile time should be  available at run time, yet the op gets `nil`.  Even if the op ran the app on a different system than the system on which the app was compiled, the op should still get `1234` as the value of the environment variable....

Comment: ...It's just that the value `1234` won't be the value of the env variable on the system on which the app was run.

Comment: Well, I was just getting ready to write a function like that, and I looked at your answer again.  I have searched hi and lo, and articles like this: https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2018/9/27/elixir-runtime-vs-compile-time-configuration/  make it seem like phoenix has a native function like yours.  Nowhere, that I can find, does it say that when you use ***system tuples*** in your config that you need to write your own function for detecting `:system` in  the `value` for a `key`.  Everything I've read makes it seem like if you use a system tuple, then certain applications will....

Comment: ...automatically look up the env variable for you at runtime.  I finally concluded that `Application.get_env()` is just a dumb lookup function, and it doesn't care whether you use `:system`  or anything else as a value for a key, and it's the application, like phoenix, that has to handle :system--if it wants to.

Answer (score 0):

When I use your configuration, then try to access the key in a controller with:

```
Application.get_env(:app, App.Notifications)[:notification_api_key]
```

I get:

```
{:system, "API_NOTIFICATION_KEY"}
```

so phoenix is not looking up the env variable.  On the other hand, if I manually set the key in the config, like this:

```
config :app, App.Notifications,
    notification_api_key: 1234
```

then I get `1234` in the controller.  I read something that said reading environment variables with `{:system, "ENV_VAR"}` was going to be deprecated at some point, and I don't see any mention of `:system` in the docs.  I'm using `phoenix 1.4.6`.

According to [this article](https://michal.muskala.eu/2017/07/30/configuring-elixir-libraries.html), you can define an `init/2` function in `endpoint.ex`, which will be called at run time--just before your phoenix app starts--which means you can directly look up environment variables at run time with `System.get_env/1`.  The `init/2` function is described in the [Phoenix.Endpoint docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-dynamic-configuration):

> **Dynamic configuration**
>
> For dynamically configuring the endpoint, such as loading data from
>   environment variables or configuration files, Phoenix invokes the
>   init/2 callback on the endpoint, passing a :supervisor atom as first
>   argument and the endpoint configuration as second.

Here's an example that I came up with:

```
  def init(:supervisor, config) do
    #IO.inspect config, label: "config"
    #IO.inspect Application.get_all_env(:app1), label: "all"

    Application.put_env(:app1, :notification_api_key, 
        System.get_env("API_NOTIFICATION_KEY"),
        persistent: true
    )

    {:ok, config}
  end
```

Then in my controller:

```
key = Application.get_env(
        :app1, App1.Notifications 
      )[:notification_api_key]

IO.inspect key, label: "key"
```

And, in the server window I see:

```
key: 1234
```

You should also realize that setting module attributes happens at compile time, so this line:

```
@api_notification_key Application.get_env(:app, App.Notifications)[:notification_api_key]
```

retrieves the env variable for the system on which the app is compiled.

I also tried setting a module attribute in my controller:

```
@attr Application.get_env(
        :app1, App1.Notifications 
      )[:notification_api_key]
```

and `init/2` defined in endpoint.ex as above, and in my controller @attr was nil--as expected.   That's because at compile time, `init/2` hasn't been called yet, so no value for `:notification_api_key` has been set.

To me, it doesn't feel right calling `Application.put_env()` in `init/2`:

```
  def init(:supervisor, config) do

    Application.put_env(:app1, :notification_api_key, 
        System.get_env("API_NOTIFICATION_KEY"),
        persistent: true
    )

    {:ok, config}
  end
```

I think I should be doing something to `config`.  Here's another example:

```
  def init(:supervisor, config) do

    IO.inspect config, label: "config"

    key = System.get_env("API_NOTIFICATION_KEY")
    new_config = Keyword.put_new(config, :notification_api_key, key)

    IO.inspect new_config, label: "inside init/2: new_config"

    {:ok, new_config}
  end
```

Then in my controller:

```
IO.inspect(
  App1Web.Endpoint.config(:notification_api_key, :not_set), 
  label: "config"
)
```

In my server window, I see:

```
config: "1234"
```

so that works, too.